# How to get validation info of an input outside of a form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

We can get the validation info if the input is in a form: `$scope.myForm.myField.$invalid` etc..

What if input is outside of a form? How can we access the info?

I guess that field data (properties of the form object) is not same thing with `ngModel`. I tried something like this but didn't worked: (the model only contains string value of the input)

```
<input ng-model="myFakeForm.myField">
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-form` directive:

```
<div ng-form="set1">
    <input name="field1" ng-model="myFakeForm.myField" ng-required="true" />
</div>
```

The input's `ngModelController` will be bound to `$scope.set1.field1`:

```
console.log($scope.set1.field1.$valid);
console.log($scope.set1.field1.$viewValue);
//... etc
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-form Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)

Comment: The `ng-form` directive makes it possible to create control groups inside a `<form>` element. These "child forms" can be used, for example, to determine the validity of a sub-group of controls.